# Get response message as string - System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException of WCF Client

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf, soap

I'm using a WCF Service Client generated using a WSDL-document that I'm using to call a SOAP web service. Sometimes, I run into XML Deserialization errors that are typically expressed with a call stack similiar to below:

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation '(any operation...)'. No characters can appear before the XML declaration. Line 1, position 2704. ---> System.Xml.XmlException: No characters can appear before the XML declaration. Line 1, position 2704.
   at System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowXmlException(XmlDictionaryReader reader, String res, String arg1, String arg2, String arg3)
   at System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.ReadDeclaration()
   at System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.ReadEndElement()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.ReadFromBodyContentsToEnd(XmlDictionaryReader reader, EnvelopeVersion envelopeVersion)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyContents(Message message, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeReply(Message message, Object[] parameters)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeReply(Message message, Object[] parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ProxyOperationRuntime.AfterReply(ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass5`1.<CreateGenericTask>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at (etc, etc...)
```

My question is:

- How do I obtain the response message stream so that I can log and investigate it as an XML string for syntax errors and schema violations?

Comment: An xml file must start with an identification <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> at first character.  The error message indicates either you have an empty string or the string doesn't start with the xml identification.

Comment: Jdweng, thanks for clarifying the exception message. However, I'm looking for a way to obtain the response message that caused it.

Comment: If the response status give a 200 Done then there is no error in the response and it is just the content of the body that is wrong.  So you need to check the status property of the response.